# Error when running Firebase 3.0 with React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native

Just loaded firebase 3.0 with react-native and getting the error

> [fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.RCTExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled
>   JS Exception: Can't find variable: document

Is react-native supported yet?

React-native code:

```
var firebase = require('firebase')

// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
    apiKey: '<apiKey>',
    authDomain: '<app>.firebaseapp.com',
    databaseURL: 'https://<app>.firebaseio.com',
    storageBucket: 'firebase-<app>.appspot.com'
};
firebase.config(config)
```

Comment: Can you show the code that is instantiating the Firebase instance? Thanks.

Comment: 3.0.0 is not compatible with React Native out of the box, we're looking into this.

Comment: 3.0.2 is also not compatible with React native(0.26.0)? I am getting same error.

Comment: 3.0.3 still not compatible

Comment: The new release of firebase Javascript SDK 3.1.0 has React Native compatibility.

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#3.1.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firebase JS SDK 3.1 [just got released](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebase-talk/Uo8E7pJJ30U/47jzoHPyBAAJ) and is now compatible with React Native!

See [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#3.1.0).

Comment: Well timed. Thanks.

Comment: In case anyone wants some more guidance here is a [tutorial](http://bitvbit.blogspot.com/2016/07/firebase-auth-v3-with-react-native.html) for Firebase email/password auth with react native for android  that I put together (the same approach can be applied for iOS).

Answer (score 13):

The newest version of firebase uses the document variables that are used in web applications and the RCTWebSocket or RCTView doesn't work the same way. (I'm not 100% sure about all the details). Anyway, you can just install an older version of firebase and it will work for you. Assuming you have npm installed follow these instructions.

1. Uninstall Firebase from your react-native project **npm uninstall firebase --save**
2. Install version 2.4.2 of firebase **npm install firebase@2.4.2 --save**
3. Happy Firebaseing!

Comment: One thing to mention is that the 2.4 npm package for auth does not work when the Firebase account is created in the new console.
Then you get the following error: `Projects created at console.firebase.google.com must use the new Firebase Authentication SDKs available from firebase.google.com/docs/auth/`

Comment: What about if we're using others services that are only available in Firebase 3, like storage?

Answer (score 2):

Firebase 3.x is not supported in RN (yet..).

### Issue

I think the issue relates to the `auth` module's dependency on the browser's `window` variable.

### Will it be officially supported?

According to the following discussion thread from the Firebase team, they are presently working on 3.x support. There is however no release time frame set.

[Google Groups Discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebase-talk/fvpjeYEg8L8/FRuWj2OmFwAJ).

### Workarounds

*Option 1 (with FB 2.x)*

From Jacob Wenger:

> If React Native support is a blocker for you, please continue to use
>   the 2.x.x SDKs until we resolve this issue. The 2.x.x SDKs will
>   continue to work, even after you migrate to the new console..`

*Option 2 (with FB 3.x)*

From Jacob Wenger:

> As a "workaround" if you don't need auth (unlikely, I know, but still
>   worth mentioning), you should be able to do the following:
>
> var app = require('firebase/app');
>   var database = require('firebase/database');

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get Firebase 3.0.2 to load in React Native by putting the following in a .js file and importing it at the top of index.ios.js:

```
global.location = {
  href: ''
};
global.screen = {

};
global.document = {
  getElementsByTagName: function(){}
};
global.parent = global;
```

There may be other gotchas - I have not explored further than this but it might get Firebase 3 working for you.

Comment: I tried your fix on both 3.0.3 and 3.0.2, however I still receive a 'Browser not supported' error screen. If it's working for you, could you possibly post more code? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To use last version of Firebase with ReactNative you can use [Firebase Bridge](https://github.com/davecoates/rn-firebase-bridge).

> I have a demo app [here](https://github.com/arkgast/grocery-app).

Answer (score 0):

**Whilst the Firebase JS SDK does work on react native now, it is mainly built for the web and is generally not the best solution for react-native.**

The Firebase Web SDK runs entirely on react native's [JS thread](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html#javascript-frame-rate), therefore affecting your application frame rate (the link explains this well).

In my tests, the native firebase SDK's has been roughly 2-3 times quicker than using the web SDK.

But on top of the potential performance impacts there's a lot of features you'll be unable to use with the web SDK on android/ios devices. For example:

- Notifications / FCM
- Offline capabilities
- Storage upload/download
- Firebase Crash Reporting
- Analytics
- Use of social authentication providers

The best approach would be to run with the native android/ios firebase sdk's and have a bridge between them and your js code (i.e. a native module setup).

Thankfully you don't have to implement this yourself, there's already modules out there to do this for you:

[react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase) for example mirrors the the web sdk's api js side but executes on the native side using the native android & ios firebase sdk's. It's fully compatible with any existing firebase js logic that you may have already implemented and is intended as a drop in replacement for the web sdk.

*(disclaimer: I am the author of react-native-firebase)*