# React Native and Firebase 3

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am trying to integrate React Native and Firebase 3 Authentication. My code.

```js
import { FIREBASE_CONFIG } from '../config';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import firebaseDatabase from 'firebase/database';
import firebaseAuth from 'firebase/auth';

firebase.initializeApp(FIREBASE_CONFIG);

export const rootRef = firebase.database();
export const authRef = firebase.auth();
```

the config

```js
module.exports = {
  FIREBASE_CONFIG: {
    apiKey: "long string from firebase",
    authDomain: "xxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "xxxxx.appspot.com"
  }
}
```

But...
[image: Error from adding Firebase 3 Auth to react]

I'm I missing something? If I am, can you point me in the right direction
config

- React Native 0.26.2
- Firebase 3.0.2

Comment: Currently, react native is not supported by the new Firebase V3 auth sdk.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37500106/this-browser-is-not-supported-in-ios-simulator

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error when running Firebase 3.0 with React Native](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37311759/error-when-running-firebase-3-0-with-react-native)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new release of firebase Javascript SDK 3.1.0 has React Native compatibility.

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#3.1.0

Comment: In case anyone wants some more guidance here is a [tutorial](http://bitvbit.blogspot.com/2016/07/firebase-auth-v3-with-react-native.html) for Firebase email/password auth with react native for android  that I put together (the same approach can be applied for iOS).

Answer (score 2):

new firebase don't support react-native.
If you want to use firebase in react-native, you use firebase version 2.4.2.
In version 3, firebase auth cannot be used but realTimeDatabase can be used in firebase3.
If you want to use firebase3 auth, I recommend using web view, [react-native-login](https://github.com/ryanmcdermott/react-native-login) but I think it's so not good.

Comment: For real? Downgrading my firebase back to 2.4.2 but these doesnt feel right. How the heck does firebase not support rn?

Answer (score 1):

To use the Firebase JS SDK 3.1+, you might have to import the whole package:

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
```

instead of just `firebase/app` etc, otherwise you could get this error:

> The React native compatibility library was not found.

Answer (score 0):

**Whilst the Firebase JS SDK does work on react native now, it is mainly built for the web and generally not the best solution for react-native.**

The Firebase Web SDK runs entirely on react native's [JS thread](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html#javascript-frame-rate), therefore affecting your application frame rate (the link explains this well).

In my tests, the native firebase SDK's has been roughly 2-3 times quicker than using the web SDK.

But on top of the potential performance impacts there's a lot of features you'll be unable to use with the web SDK on android/ios devices. For example:

- Notifications / FCM
- Storage upload/download
- Firebase Crash Reporting
- Analytics
- Use of social authentication providers

The best approach would be to run with the native android/ios firebase sdk's and have a bridge between them and your js code (i.e. a native module setup).

Thankfully you don't have to implement this yourself, there's already modules out there to do this for you:

[react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase) for example mirrors the the web sdk's api js side but executes on the native side using the native android & ios firebase sdk's. It's fully compatible with any existing firebase js logic that you may have already implemented and is intended as a drop in replacement for the web sdk.

*(disclaimer: I am the author of react-native-firebase)*