# Is possible to use latest firebase (v3) analytics tools with react native?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-analytics

Hi Its possible to use firebase Analytics (just the analytics features) with React Native?

For avoidance of doubt. I'm well aware that current Firebase (V3 SKD) is not fully compatible with RN for all features ([React Native and Firebase 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37496639/react-native-and-firebase-3))

For now I'm planing to use solely the Analytics (core firebase SKD)

Tks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with this React Native component for Firebase Analytics? 
https://github.com/evollu/react-native-firebase-analytics

Comment: Fantastic, looks like this was released a few days ago. Answering your question No! but I'll definitely git it a try.