# This Browser is not supported in iOS simulator

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am getting an error in react-native, `This Browser is not supported`, in the iOS simulator, after running the following code:

```
const firebase = require('firebase')
const firebaseConfig = require('./firebase-config')
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

firebase.database().ref('test').set('hello')
```

firebase-config contains a databaseURL.

why?

Comment: For now use this way http://stackoverflow.com/a/37313694/2976753

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Firebaser here*

The new Firebase Authentication currently doesn't work in React Native due to a dependency on the `window` object. We're looking if that's something we can improve, but no guarantees.

From [Jacob's post on the firebase-talk list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebase-talk/0iY0rtrbFQg/9cNuh_3TFwAJ):

> As a "workaround" if you don't need auth (unlikely, I know, but still worth mentioning), you should be able to do the following:

```
var app = require('firebase/app');
var database = require('firebase/database');
```

Comment: Running into the same problem with Chrome App :(

Comment: But why it doesn't work even inside an iframe? iframe has the `window` object, no?

Comment: Hi Frank, any update on this? I'm stuck since I can't use Firebase 2 with my account (new Google console). Or am I?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, the new Firebase Javascript client library depends on localStorage, and thus fails to start in some cases, such as Safari in Private Browsing Mode.

As a workaround, I uploaded a patched version of the new client library to github:
https://github.com/urish/firebase-localstorage-fix/blob/master/firebase.js

I do hope that the team will fix this issue soon, but in the meantime the patched version does the trick for me.