# Firebase App named DEFAULT already exist

Tags: firebase, react-native

I am trying to set up firebase for small react native app and getting this error:
**Firebase App named DEFAULT already exist** . My be somebody got in this trouble too?

I am using firebase v. 3.2.1 and react native v. 0.31.0.

And app initialization as follows:

```
  import * as firebase from 'firebase';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "key",
  authDomain: "",
  databaseURL: "",
  storageBucket: "",
} export default class Root extends Component {


 constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    var firebase= firebase.initializeApp('firebaseConfig');
  }
```

Comment: seems like it is because of single quotes , try this syntax: `firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);`

Comment: Thanks, it helped :)

Comment: And now another one :  undefined is not an object evaluating firebase.initializeApp . Any thoughts ?

Comment: I found the solution in here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37311759/error-when-running-firebase-3-0-with-react-native